# How can I setup multiple wordpress installs on one domain?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I wish to set up 2 wordpress installs for the same website. One for US english and one for UK english. They need to be more bespoke than just using a language plugin and so I will use 2 similar themes.

Both need to be on the same parent domain "foo.com" one will be foo.com/en-gb and the other foo.com/en-us.

I can't work out how to go about this efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WordPress multisite network allows you to run and manage multiple WordPress sites from a single WordPress installation.

You can create new sites instantly and manage them using the same username and password. You can even allow other users to signup and create their own blogs on your domain.

You can efficiently maintain your two instances with whatever the languages you need

```
foo.com/en-gb and foo.com/en-us
```

Please check wordpress codex for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you shoud see Wordpress multisite, take a look here https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network?